# How do I tell if an svn project has tags or branches?

Tags: svn

I'm working on migrating several SVN repositories to git and I want to make sure I'm not missing anything. I'd like to see whether the project has any existing tags or branches so I don't miss anything in porting it. Is there a command I can use similiar to `git branch` where I can see of branches? (And something similar for tags?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An svn repository is just a versioned directory tree. Tags and branches are just a convention, not a built-in concept like in most other tools. Normally these are stored in specially named "tags" and "branches" directories. So if you have all directories under the repository root, then you have not missed anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

BarFooBar,

like Ben said. Branches and Tags are only conventions in SVN.
But anyway you can analyse if you have branches in your SVN repo.

Check out the tortoiseSVN, which can show you the branches graphically. Also it can show you all svn copies, which may be a branch or a tag.

I am not sure if you need really the tags to verify.

I would also suggest you to check:
http://svnmapper.tigris.org/

If you can say for sure, your developers have used the SVN convention to place tags into /tags and branches into /branches your are fine to check only them. If not you will need one of the above tools.

Wish you good luck on your migration.

(Maybe you can update me after migration? Would really like to know your experience, since we are also thinking to migrate...)